# EOSIO-java maven dependencies issue

Tags: java, blockchain

I am trying to connect Java to EOSIO using eosio-java example.

tried with gradle and maven in java, with the below example

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-java#installation

Two classes (EosioJavaRpcProviderImpl & AbiEosSerializationProviderImpl) are not found. I am stuck between Java and Android.

The classes - EosioJavaRpcProviderImpl & AbiEosSerializationProviderImpl provided as aar file and java uses jar file and can't find these classes to connect to EOSIO.

Any help will be much appreciated.

(EosioJavaRpcProviderImpl & AbiEosSerializationProviderImpl)

Comment: The only question I can see here is asking if anyone has used it. I am sure that is not really what you want to know the answer to (*"yes, some people have used it"* is the answer), so please see [ask] and edit your question to be specific.